# Model Validation Using Residual Plot?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, residuals, validation

I am trying to validate a given multiple linear regression model on a new dataset (a dataset that has not been "seen" by this model). Is it okay to discard this model on account of it showing a pattern in the residual plot for the predictions on this new dataset, even though the prediction intervals do actually validate the model?

EDIT: Added more information:

Here is the residual plot

[image: The residual plot]

1. A previous research paper had formulated a multiple linear regression model for an infectious disease in a city for an earlier period. I have found more data for the same disease in the same city for a recent period. So the test data is from a different sample as train data. However one would expect that the underlying processes are the same and so the same model should fit for this new dataset as well.
2. The train set (as stated in the paper) had 48 data points, while my test set has 76 data points.
3. This is what I think I should do - Since the residual plot (based on the predictions from the previous model on the new data) showed a pattern (indicating a bad fit - this my reason to discard the old model), I am now proceeding to select the independent variables for the new data, which I would use to fit a new model.

Comment: Have you considered performing a goodness-of-fit test on the validation set residuals?

Comment: I have performed the goodness-of-fit test between the observed and the predicted values. The R-squared is indeed quite low (around 0.24). I do not, however, understand by what do you mean by "a goodness-of-fit test on ... the residuals". I mean, I should test the goodness-of-fit of what with the residuals?